# Localhost API returning valid JSON is not fetched

Tags: javascript, json, tomcat, cors

I am using Apache tomcat to host my local server and I have created Java rest API using jersey. Now I am returning JSON object which works fine when i open it in browser or postman and it is also valid JSON object.

```
[
{
    "algo_name": "First Come First Served",
    "running_time": 13.125098
},
{
    "algo_name": "Shortest Job First",
    "running_time": 22.620548
},
{
    "algo_name": "Shortest Remaining Time",
    "running_time": 21.530843
},
{
    "algo_name": "Non-Preemptive Highest Priority First",
    "running_time": 15.412454
},
{
    "algo_name": "Round Robin",
    "running_time": 20.904071
}
]
```

But when I try to read it from javascipt in html file using url "http://localhost:8080/algo/webapi/handler/100/100/100/4", I can not fetch json from it.

```
let url = 'http://localhost:8080/algo/webapi/handler/100/100/100/4';

fetch( url, {
    method: 'get'
}).then( function( response ) {
    alert("Success");
}).catch( function( err ) {
    alert("OOps");
});
```

Above code gives "OOps" in my browser. I am not able to get response from javascript on local machine. Below is error log in browser.

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8080/algo/webapi/handler/100/100/100/4:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource.Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque 
response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the 
resource with CORS disabled.
```

I also tried returning xml and it also is not working? What is problem?

Comment: You should have a look at `err`.

Comment: Did you try to fetch the JSON using `cURL` or Postman, or by any other medium?

Comment: Yes I used postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this is that I did not include CORS response library in JAVA Api. Thogh Postman can give response without it. Browsers do not.